# SQL 2000 Maintenance Scripts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Hi I've stumbled into the administration of a Legacy SQL 2000 server that has had next to no maintenance for the past 8 years (and is very slow).  As I have only been doing DBA / PT for the past 2 years (I'm primarily a Developer) I don't have allot of experience on 2000.  Can anyone point me in the direction of some maintenance, tuning scripts.  Just figured I'd ask first before I reinvent the wheel for something I will rarely use.

Thanks Guys / Girls !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only recently waved goodbye to the last SQL2K server I looked after, so have a few scripts in the toolbox still. You could also root around in the [SSC scripts archive](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts).

Here's an old index maintenance script by [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/):

```
-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
-- Written by Kimberly L. Tripp - all rights reserved.
-- UPDATE: AUGUST 25, 2004
-- RE: Fix for DESC clustered indexes. There are no errors for DESC in 
-- nonclustered indexes. Thanks!
-- 
-- For more scripts and sample code, check out 
--  http://www.SQLSkills.com
--
-- Disclaimer - Thoroughly test this script, execute at your own risk.
-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

-- Execute this whole script to create the sp_RebuildIndexes stored procedure in Master.
-- Best Viewed with Courier New 12pt. and Tabs saved as 4 spaces not 8. (Tools, Options, Editor)

-- To use the sp_RebuildIndexes procedure once created use:
-- sp_RebuildIndexes 
--      To Rebuild All Indexes on All Tables for all that have a Scan Density < 100%
-- sp_RebuildIndexes @ScanDensity = 80
--      To Rebuild All Indexes on All Tables with a Scan Density of < 80%
-- sp_RebuildIndexes 'Authors'
--      To Rebuild All Indexes on the authors table - for a Scan Density of < 100%
-- sp_RebuildIndexes 'Authors', 80
--      To Rebuild All Indexes on the authors table - for a Scan Density of < 80%
-- Object Name and ScanDensity are both optional parameters. 
-- ScanDensity must be a whole number between 1 and 100.

USE master
go
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('sp_RebuildClusteredIndex'), 'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_RebuildClusteredIndex
go

IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('sp_RebuildIndexes'), 'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_RebuildIndexes
go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RebuildClusteredIndex
(
    @TableName      sysname     = NULL,
    @IndexName      sysname     = NULL
)       
AS
-- Written by Kimberly L. Tripp of SYSolutions, Inc.
-- For more code samples go to http://www.sqlskills.com
-- NOTE: If your clustered index is NOT unique then rebuilding the clustered
-- index will cause the non-clustered indexes to be rebuilt. If the nonclustered
-- indexes were fragmented then this series of scripts will build them again.
-- This is something this script DOES NOT look for...because you should not create
-- clustered indexes on a non-unique column or composite set of columns.
IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), 'IsUserTable') = 0 
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), 'IsView') = 0) 
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('Object: %s exists but is NOT a User-defined Table. This procedure only accepts valid table names to process for index rebuilds.', 16, 1, @TableName)
                RETURN
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), 'IsTable') IS NULL
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Object: %s does not exist within this database. Please check the table name and location (which database?). This procedure only accepts existing table names to process for index rebuilds.', 16, 1, @TableName)
                        RETURN
                    END
            END
    END

IF @IndexName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF INDEXPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), @IndexName, 'IsClustered') = 0
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('Index: %s exists but is a Clustered Index. This procedure only accepts valid table names and their clustered indexes for rebuilds.', 16, 1, @IndexName)
                RETURN
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF INDEXPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), @IndexName, 'IsClustered') IS NULL
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @TableName, @IndexName, INDEXPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), @IndexName, 'IsClustered')
                        RAISERROR('There is no index with name:%s on this table. Please check the table name and index name as well as location (which database?). This procedure only accepts existing table names and their clustered indexes for rebuilds.', 16, 1, @IndexName)
                        RETURN
                    END
            END
    END

-- So now we have a valid table, a valid CLUSTERED index and we're ready to rebuild.
    -- Here's a quick overview of what this code will do:
        -- Get the Column List and Index Defintion (Use the output from sp_helpindex)
        -- Figure out if it's UNIQUE - to specify in CREATE INDEX statement
        -- Build and Execute the CREATE INDEX command through dynamic string execution

DECLARE @ExecStr        nvarchar(4000) -- more than enough even if 16 cols of 128 chars, 
                                       -- Tablename of 128 and Indexname of 128...
                                       -- but if this is the case you have other problems :).
        , @ColList      nvarchar(3000)
        , @Unique       nvarchar(7)    -- Will be either '' or 'Unique ' and added to CR Index String
        , @FillFactor   nvarchar(100)

CREATE TABLE #IndexInfo
(
    IndexName   sysname,
    IndexDesc   varchar(210),
    IndexKeys   nvarchar(2126)
)

INSERT INTO #IndexInfo 
    EXEC sp_helpindex @TableName

SELECT @ColList = IndexKeys
         , @Unique = CASE 
                        WHEN IndexDesc LIKE 'clustered, unique%' 
                            THEN 'Unique '
                        ELSE ''
                    END --CASE Expression
         , @FillFactor = ', FILLFACTOR = ' + NULLIF(convert(nvarchar(3), 
                        (SELECT OrigFillFactor 
                            FROM sysindexes 
                            WHERE id = object_id(@TableName) 
                                AND Name = @IndexName)), 0)
FROM #IndexInfo
WHERE IndexName = @IndexName

SELECT @ExecStr = 'CREATE ' + @Unique + 'CLUSTERED INDEX ' 
                        + QUOTENAME(@IndexName, ']') + ' ON ' 
                        + QUOTENAME(@TableName, ']') + '(' + @collist 
                        + ') WITH DROP_EXISTING ' + ISNULL(@FillFactor, '')

-- Added Aug 25, 04: FIX FOR DESC Indexes.
SELECT @ExecStr = REPLACE(@ExecStr, '(-)', ' DESC')

-- For testing the String
-- SELECT @ExecStr

-- Create the Clustered Index
EXEC(@ExecStr)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RebuildIndexes
(
    @TableName      sysname     = NULL,
    @ScanDensity    tinyint     = 100
)
AS
-- Written by Kimberly L. Tripp of SYSolutions, Inc.
-- For more code samples go to http://www.sqlskills.com
--
-- This procedure will get the Fragmentation information
-- for all tables and indexes within the database. 
-- Programmatically it will then walk the list rebuilding all
-- indexes that have a scan density less than the value 
-- passed in - by default any less than 100% contiguous.
-- 
-- Use this script as a starting point. Modify it for your
-- options, ideas, etc. - and then schedule it to run regularly.
-- 
-- NOTE - This gathers density information for all tables 
-- and all indexes. This might be time consuming on large
-- databases. 
-- 
-- DISCLAIMER - Execute at your own risk. TEST THIS FIRST. 
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF @ScanDensity IS NULL
    SET @ScanDensity = 100

IF @ScanDensity NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 100
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Value supplied:%i is not valid. @ScanDensity is a percentage. Please supply a value for Scan Density between 1 and 100.', 16, 1, @ScanDensity)
        RETURN
    END
IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), 'IsUserTable') = 0 
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('Object: %s exists but is NOT a User-defined Table. This procedure only accepts valid table names to process for index rebuilds.', 16, 1, @TableName)
                RETURN
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(@TableName), 'IsTable') IS NULL
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Object: %s does not exist within this database. Please check the table name and location (which database?). This procedure only accepts existing table names to process for index rebuilds.', 16, 1, @TableName)
                        RETURN
                    END
            END
    END

-- Otherwise the Object Exists and it is a table so we'll continue from here. 
-- First thing to do is create a temp location for the data returned from DBCC SHOWCONTIG

CREATE TABLE #ShowContigOutput
(
    ObjectName          sysname,
    ObjectId                int,
    IndexName               sysname,
    IndexId                 tinyint,
    [Level]                 tinyint,
    Pages                   int,
    [Rows]                  bigint,
    MinimumRecordSize       smallint,
    MaximumRecordSize   smallint,
    AverageRecordSize       smallint,
    ForwardedRecords        bigint,
    Extents                 int,
    ExtentSwitches          numeric(10,2),
    AverageFreeBytes        numeric(10,2),
    AveragePageDensity  numeric(10,2),
    ScanDensity         numeric(10,2),
    BestCount               int,
    ActualCount         int,
    LogicalFragmentation    numeric(10,2),
    ExtentFragmentation numeric(10,2)
)                            

IF @TableName IS NOT NULL -- then we only need the showcontig output for that table
    INSERT #ShowContigOutput
        EXEC('DBCC SHOWCONTIG (' + @TableName + ') WITH FAST, ALL_INDEXES, TABLERESULTS') 
ELSE -- All Tables, All Indexes Will be processed.
    INSERT #ShowContigOutput
        EXEC('DBCC SHOWCONTIG WITH FAST, ALL_INDEXES, TABLERESULTS') 
PRINT N' '

-- Quick test to see if everything is getting here correctly
-- SELECT * FROM #ShowContigOutput

-- Walk the showcontig output table skipping all replication tables as well as all tables necessary for
-- the UI. This is also where you can list large tables that you don't want to rebuild all at one time.
-- NOTE: If you take out a large table from rebuilding this script may have already checked density
-- meaning that the expense in terms of time may have been expensive.
-- Also, you should use a different procedure to rebuild a large table specifically. 
-- Even when you pass in the tablename it will be avoided here if MANUALLY added to the 
-- list by you. 
-- Test, Test, Test!

DECLARE @ObjectName             sysname,
            @IndexName          sysname,
            @QObjectName            nvarchar(258),
            @QIndexName         nvarchar(258),
            @IndexID                tinyint,
            @ActualScanDensity  numeric(10,2),
            @InformationalOutput    nvarchar(4000),
            @StartTime              datetime,
            @EndTime                datetime

DECLARE TableIndexList CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT ObjectName, IndexName, IndexID, ScanDensity 
    FROM #ShowContigOutput AS sc
        JOIN sysobjects AS so ON sc.ObjectID = so.id
    WHERE sc.ScanDensity < @ScanDensity 
        AND (OBJECTPROPERTY(sc.ObjectID, 'IsUserTable') = 1 
                OR OBJECTPROPERTY(sc.ObjectID, 'IsView') = 1)
        AND so.STATUS > 0
        AND sc.IndexID BETWEEN 1 AND 250 
        AND sc.ObjectName NOT IN ('dtproperties') 
            -- Here you can list large tables you do not WANT rebuilt.
    ORDER BY sc.ObjectName, sc.IndexID

OPEN TableIndexList

FETCH NEXT FROM TableIndexList 
    INTO @ObjectName, @IndexName, @IndexID, @ActualScanDensity

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @QObjectName = QUOTENAME(@ObjectName, ']')
        SELECT @QIndexName = QUOTENAME(@IndexName, ']')
        SELECT @InformationalOutput = N'Processing Table: ' + RTRIM(UPPER(@QObjectName)) 
                                            + N' Rebuilding Index: ' + RTRIM(UPPER(@QIndexName)) 
        PRINT @InformationalOutput
        IF @IndexID = 1 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @StartTime = getdate()
            EXEC sp_RebuildClusteredIndex @ObjectName, @IndexName
            SELECT @EndTime = getdate()
            SELECT @InformationalOutput = N'Total Time to process = ' + convert(nvarchar, datediff(ms, @StartTime, @EndTime)) + N' ms'
            PRINT @InformationalOutput 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @StartTime = getdate()
            EXEC('DBCC DBREINDEX(' + @QObjectName + ', ' + @QIndexName + ') WITH NO_INFOMSGS')
            SELECT @EndTime = getdate()
            SELECT @InformationalOutput = N'Total Time to process = ' + convert(nvarchar, datediff(ms, @StartTime, @EndTime)) + N' ms'
            PRINT @InformationalOutput 
        END
        PRINT N' '
        FETCH NEXT FROM TableIndexList 
            INTO @ObjectName, @IndexName, @IndexID, @ActualScanDensity
    END
END
PRINT N' '
SELECT @InformationalOutput = N'***** All Indexes have been rebuilt.  ***** ' 
PRINT @InformationalOutput 
DEALLOCATE TableIndexList 
go
```

Wait stats, the old way (not sure where this originated from):

```
use master
go

if ((object_id('sp_waitstats') is not null) and (objectproperty(object_id('sp_waitstats'), 'IsProcedure') = 1))
    drop proc [dbo].[sp_waitstats]
go

create proc [dbo].[sp_waitstats] @orderby nvarchar(10) = N'total'
as

set nocount on

if (lower(@orderby) not in ('total', 'resource', 'signal'))
begin
    raiserror('Error: incorrect @orderby value, use ''total'', ''resource'', ''signal''', 10, 1) with nowait
    return
end

declare @requests   bigint,
        @totalwait  numeric(20, 5),
        @totalres   numeric(20, 5),
        @totalsig   numeric(20, 5),
        @endtime    datetime,
        @begintime  datetime

create table [#waitstats]
(
    [wait type]         varchar(80) not null, 
    [requests]          bigint not null,
    [wait time]         numeric(20, 5) not null,
    [signal wait time]  numeric(20, 5) not null,
    [now]               datetime not null default getdate()
)

insert into [#waitstats]([wait type], [requests], [wait time], [signal wait time])      
    exec ('dbcc sqlperf(waitstats) with tableresults, no_infomsgs')

select  @begintime = min([now]),
        @endtime   = max([now])
from    [#waitstats] 
where   [wait type] = 'Total'

--- subtract waitfor, sleep, and resource_queue from Total
select  @requests  = sum([requests]),
        @totalwait = sum([wait time]),
        @totalres  = sum(([wait time] - [signal wait time])),
        @totalsig  = sum([signal wait time]) 
from    [#waitstats] 
where   [wait type] not in ('WAITFOR','SLEEP','RESOURCE_QUEUE', 'Total', '***total***') 
and     [now] = @endtime

-- insert adjusted totals, rank by percentage descending
delete  [#waitstats] 
where   [wait type] = '***total***' 
and     [now] = @endtime

insert into #waitstats values('***total***', @requests, @totalwait, @totalsig, @endtime)

if (@orderby = N'total')
begin

    select  [requests],
            [wait type],
            [total wait time]       = [wait time],
            [resource wait time]    = [wait time] - [signal wait time],
            [signal wait time],
            [%total wait time]      = case @totalwait when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * [wait time] / @totalwait as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [%resource wait time]   = case @totalres  when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * ([wait time] - [signal wait time]) / @totalres as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [%signal wait time]     = case @totalsig  when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * [signal wait time] / @totalsig as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg total wait time]   = case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalwait / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg resource wait time]= case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalres  / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg signal wait time]  = case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalsig  / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end
    from    [#waitstats]
    where   [wait type] not in ('WAITFOR','SLEEP','RESOURCE_QUEUE', 'Total')
    and     [now] = @endtime
    order by [%total wait time] desc

end

if (@orderby = N'resource')
begin

    select  [requests],
            [wait type],
            [total wait time]       = [wait time],
            [resource wait time]    = [wait time] - [signal wait time],
            [signal wait time],
            [%total wait time]      = case @totalwait when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * [wait time] / @totalwait as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [%resource wait time]   = case @totalres  when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * ([wait time] - [signal wait time]) / @totalres as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [%signal wait time]     = case @totalsig  when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * [signal wait time] / @totalsig as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg total wait time]   = case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalwait / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg resource wait time]= case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalres  / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg signal wait time]  = case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalsig  / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end
    from    [#waitstats]
    where   [wait type] not in ('WAITFOR','SLEEP','RESOURCE_QUEUE', 'Total')
    and     [now] = @endtime
    order by [%resource wait time] desc

end

if (@orderby = N'signal')
begin

    select  [requests],
            [wait type],
            [total wait time]       = [wait time],
            [resource wait time]    = [wait time] - [signal wait time],
            [signal wait time],
            [%total wait time]      = case @totalwait when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * [wait time] / @totalwait as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [%resource wait time]   = case @totalres  when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * ([wait time] - [signal wait time]) / @totalres as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [%signal wait time]     = case @totalsig  when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * [signal wait time] / @totalsig as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg total wait time]   = case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalwait / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg resource wait time]= case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalres  / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end,
            [avg signal wait time]  = case [requests] when 0 then 0 else cast(100 * @totalsig  / [requests] as numeric(20, 5)) end
    from    [#waitstats]
    where   [wait type] not in ('WAITFOR','SLEEP','RESOURCE_QUEUE', 'Total')
    and     [now] = @endtime
    order by [%signal wait time] desc

end

drop table [#waitstats]
go

exec sp_waitstats
exec sp_waitstats @orderby = 'total'
exec sp_waitstats @orderby = 'resource'
exec sp_waitstats @orderby = 'signal'
go
```

Comment: Thanks Mark This is exactly what I was looking for ... The Indexes are a hot mess so this we be very helpful.